# Executing PHP script has different results when run in CLI and by node.js script

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, exec, command-line-interface

I'm completely lost with figuring out why my PHP script produces different results when run via CLI (producing the right results) vs when run within Node.js via the exec function.

Here's my PHP. Note the `fopen('blah.txt', 'w')` line, which is what I'm using to check if the script reaches that place.

**calculator.php**

```
class calculator{

    public static $_var = array();

    public function calculate($xml, $xsl, $frequency){
        $reader = new DOMDocument;
        if(!$reader->load($xsl)) throw new Exception('XSL Could not be loaded: ' . $xsl);

        $processor = new XSLTProcessor;
        $processor->importStyleSheet($reader);
        $processor->registerPHPFunctions();
        $processor->setParameter('', 'frequency', $frequency);

        $dictionary = new DOMDocument;
        if(!$dictionary->load($xml)) throw new Exception('XML Could not be loaded: ' . $xml);

        $processor->transformToXML($dictionary);
    }

    public static function connectNodes($name, $dataset, $processor, $destination, $frequency){
        $var = self::$_var;
        self::$_var = array();

        $test = fopen('blah.txt', 'w');
        fclose($test);

        ob_start();
        require 'templates/' . $processor . '.php';
        $xsltSheet = new DOMDocument;
        $xsltSheet->loadXML(ob_get_clean());

        $xsltProc = new XSLTProcessor;
        $xsltProc->importStyleSheet($xsltSheet);

        $dataSet = new DOMDocument;
        if(is_file('../dataFiles/xml/' . $dataset . '.xml') && calculator::makedirs('../dataFiles/json/' . $destination . '/' . $frequency)){
            //proceed only if the dataset exists and the folders are created correctly
            $dataSet->load('../dataFiles/xml/' . $dataset . '.xml');
            if(!is_file('../dataFiles/json/' . $destination . '/' . $frequency . '/' . $name . '.json')){
                $filemaker = fopen('../dataFiles/json/' . $destination . '/' . $frequency . '/' . $name . '.json', 'w');
                fclose($filemaker);
            }
            $xsltProc->transformToURI($dataSet, '../dataFiles/json/' . $destination . '/' . $frequency . '/' . $name . '.json');
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Either dataset does not exist('. $dataset .'), or directories could not be created (dataFiles/json/'. $destination . '/' . $frequency .')');
        }

    }

    public static function populateVarWithXPath($var){
        self::$_var[] = $var;
    }

    public static function makedirs($dirpath, $mode=0777) {
        return is_dir($dirpath) || mkdir($dirpath, $mode, true);
    }

}
```

When I run this via the CLI, blah.txt is created in the directory of where the script is ran. But when I run this via Node.js, it doesn't create blah.txt!

Here's my node script:

**script runner**

```
var ipc = require('./ipc');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

ipc.listen(function(frequency){

    if(frequency.toString().match(/integrator /)){
        var freq = frequency.toString().replace(/integrator /, '');
        console.log('Received message: ' + freq);

        var cmd = exec('php use_calculator.php metricsDictionary.xml metricsXmlReader.xsl ' + frequency);

        cmd.on('close', function(exitCode, stdout, stderr){
            if(exitCode === 0){
                console.log('exitcode: ' + exitCode + ' ; stdout: ' + stdout + ' ; stderr: ' + stderr);

            } else {
                console.log('Try again?');
            }
        });

        cmd.on('error', function(err){
            throw err;
        });

    }

});
```

The funny thing here is, if I move my blah.txt to the calculate() function (which will run first), both CLI and node will create the file.

---

### **A little more context:**

The use_calculator.php file will call the calculate() function and pass the three required arguments to it. Then, within calculate(), it will do an XML and XSL file merge.

Within the XSL are rules on how to handle the XML data, and what it does is call the connectNodes() function -- which will process new XML and XSL. It's like an inception of XML/XSL.

The point is there's one XML file listing all the details of what and how other XML data should be processed. That file is read in calculate(). Then as it calculates each piece of data, it calls the connectNode() function in an inception-like way.

To make things clearer (I hope), here's the metricsXmlReader.xsl which calls connectNodes()

**metricsXmlReader.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">

    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="metrics">
        <xsl:for-each select="metric">
            <xsl:if test="frequency = $frequency">
                <xsl:for-each select="xpath/var">
                    <xsl:variable name="pusher" select="php:functionString('calculator::populateVarWithXPath', .)" />
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:variable name="trigger" select="php:functionString('calculator::connectNodes', name, dataset, processor, destination, frequency)" />   
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Presumably node is run as a different user to the CLI, do they have the same permissions?

Comment: Try spawning a shell instead and pipe the php command as stdin and check whats happening by listening to on data

Comment: Hi cswl, that sounds good. How do you suggest I do that? You mean use spawn() instead of exec()?

Comment: Clarification on the permissions of my account. I log in not as root (in fact the account has low privileges). Then I use this command to run everything: /usr/bin/sudo su - apache -c '<commands here>' and apache has root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that, wherever PHP is trying to write the file to, it can't. You could try an absolute path with rights for everyone like /tmp.

Also you should make sure that you can handle parallel requests. Because this doesn't scale. As already mentioned pipeing is a solution.

HP

PS: Have you tried it?

Comment: I was worried it wouldn't scale, because it's expensive to spawn new processes. But, this is a CPU-intensive calculation, so shouldn't Node be passing the work to another process, anyway?

Comment: I mean it doesn't scale because you can only open blah.txt once to write to (at least if there is no mechanism to provide always new folders for every process to write to).
I would really start digging from the ground and see if you can write a file at all at a place where you can write to and then determine where is the place where your file should be openend.